# C++:questions vector STL

Tags: c++, function, vector, stl

I did getting divisors by calling functions named `getDivisors` and return their values formatted by container `vector<int>`.

Since I am a new to `C++` container, I tried to print my divisor integers by for loops using an iterator. However, in my opinions, it seems too complex.
Is there any easy way to show stored integers in vector `STL`?

And I don't get it why the iterator variable `it is pointer type? Could you explain it more about it? I was confused that the compilers show the error message when I did`it`not`it`

Below are my simple codes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> getDivisors(int input)
{
    vector<int> divisors;
    divisors.push_back(1); //default
    for (int i = 2; i < input; i++){
        if (input%i == 0){
            divisors.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    return divisors;
}

void solve()
{
    int input;
    cin >> input;
    vector<int> divisors = getDivisors(input);

    for (vector<int>::iterator it = divisors.begin(); it != divisors.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        solve();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't mentioned which compiler you are using, but in C++11 conforming compilers you can use [auto](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) and the [Ranged-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

```
for (auto i : divisors)
{
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

> `i` here is not an iterator, it's the container template type which in your case is an `int`

A pointer is a kind of [iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator) specifically a [random access iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator). Iterators are designed as abstractions of pointers with operators like `*`, `->`, `++`, `--`, etc. for accessing [containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/).

For C++ programmers, [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/) is your friend.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How to know my C++ compiler is C++11 or below in Visual Studio?

Comment: Visual studio 2013 onwards offers C++11 support

Comment: The "range for" is a C++ 11 feature that was added in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Alternatively you can also see using "std::for_each"

Answer (score 2):

It is not a pointer, it's an iterator. It overrides `operator *` to provide pointer-like behavior. You can read more about C++ STL to understand that.

If you are using C++11 or later, use this:

```
for (auto x : divisors) cout << x << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterators are convenient abstractions which help in accessing a container. They are not pointers.

One of the things you've got to be careful about, is that an iterator can get invalidated if the container associated with it changes substantially

Get a good book on STL and get the fundamentals right before proceeding. Here's a primer but it can only do so much.
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/iterators.html